# How to set returnKeyType for iOS from QML

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qt5.12

I have a QML TextField as an input for a search field.  Natively in iOS when a user clicks on the TextField the default iOS keyboard is presented.  The "returnKey" of the default iOS keyboard just says "done".  I would like it to say "Search" instead.

I see the iOS docs that show the different types of returnKeys you can have, which does list "Search" and an option:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624446-returnkeytype
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireturnkeytype

But I'm not sure how I can access these within QML.  Can this be changed from a QML application?

```
TextField {
    id: textInputSearchTerms
    font.pointSize: 20
    anchors.fill: parent
    placeholderText: "Search..."
    inputMask: qsTr("")
}
```

I am using Qt 5.12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as of Qt 5.6:

```
TextField {
    EnterKey.type: Qt.EnterKeySearch
}
```

[Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-enterkey.html)